# Simple examples of the diagonal lemma

Tags: logic, model-theory, computability

According to Boolos' *Computability and Logic*, the diagonal lemma states:

> Let $T$ be a theory containing $\mathbf{Q}$.  Then for any formula $B(y)$ there is a sentence $G$ such that $\vdash_T\,G\leftrightarrow B(\ulcorner G\urcorner).$

$\mathbf{Q}$ is Boolos' version of Robinson arithmetic.  The proof of the lemma involves constructing a sentence $G$ which one, in practice, could not possibly write down.  But what if we take some simple examples.

- Here's one: let $B(y)$ be $\mathbf{0}^{\prime\prime}<y$.  Then we can take $G$ to be the sentence $\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}$, correct?  Certainly $\ulcorner G\urcorner$ is much greater than 2, so $G\leftrightarrow B(\ulcorner G\urcorner)$ is valid.
- Here's another: let $B(y)$ be $y<\mathbf{0}^{\prime\prime}$.  There aren't any sentences with Godel numbers less than 2, so we choose any false sentence we like for $G$, such as $\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}^\prime$.  Then, once again, $G\leftrightarrow B(\ulcorner G\urcorner)$ is valid.

I am correct in believing that, for *very simple formulas* $B(y)$ of arithmetic, it's actually incredibly easy to construct a diagonal sentence $G$?  In general, though, is this method not feasible?

Comment: "The proof of the lemma involves constructing a sentence  which one, in practice, could not possibly write down." It's not actually that bad - long, yes, but I don't think they're more than a few pages long (at least, according to reasonably efficient coding systems).

Comment: Good point Noah.  Replace "possibly" with "easily".